# The embedding of manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $f$ is a smooth function on it, is it necessarily that there is an embedding $F$ of $M$ to $\mathbb R^k$ such that the first component of $F$ is $f$ ？

Comment: Why do people vote such minimalistic and underspecified questions up?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to look for an embedding $F$ with no restriction on $k$, then the answer is yes. Actually we can set $k=2m+1$ where $m$ is the dimension of the manifold $M$. By Whitney embedding theorem (see [Whitney embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem), there exists an embedding $G$ from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. Now take $F$ to be $F=(f,G)$.

Comment: In order to make $F$ an embedding, we should choose $G$ to be proper.